# QObject::connect and template causes issue

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qobject

I would like to have a proxy for `QObject::connect` in a base class. The goal is to store all the `QMetaObject::Connection` returned by `connect` in a vector.

```
class MyBaseClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT;

    template <typename... Args>
    void addConnection(Args... args) {
        auto c = this->connect(args...);
        if (c) {
            connections.push_back(c);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the connection does not work anymore. When I emit a signal from a class that inherits `MyBaseClass`, it does nothing. For example, this does work :

```
connect(this, &ClassThatInheritsBaseClass::valueChanged, [this](int v) {
    qDebug() << QString::number(value);
}
```

But this does not work :

```
addConnection(this, &ClassThatInheritsBaseClass::valueChanged, [this](int v) {
    qDebug() << QString::number(value);
}
```

Could someone explain me why it does not work ? And how to make it work ?

Comment: Last time I checked, Qt didn't support variadic templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid code and it works with `variadic templates` and with `std::tuple`. Code below is fully working example:

Header:

```
#ifndef MYBASECLASS_H
#define MYBASECLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyBaseClass : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT
    std::vector<QMetaObject::Connection> connections;
public:
    template <typename T>
    void addConnectionTuple(const T& t) {//not best
        auto c = this->connect(std::get<0>(t),std::get<1>(t),std::get<2>(t));
        if (c) {
            connections.push_back(c);
        }
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void addConnection(Args... args) {
        auto c = this->connect(args...);
        if (c) {
            connections.push_back(c);
        }
    }
};

#endif // MYBASECLASS_H
```

Code:

```
QObject aa;
MyBaseClass bb;
std::make_tuple(10,5);
    bb.addConnectionTuple(std::make_tuple(&aa, &QObject::objectNameChanged, [](QString v) {
    qDebug() << v;
}));
aa.setObjectName("super");
```

Or

```
QObject aa;
MyBaseClass bb;
std::make_tuple(10,5);
    bb.addConnection(&aa, &QObject::objectNameChanged, [](QString v) {
    qDebug() << v;
});
aa.setObjectName("super");
```

Also `std::forward` works too.

```
template <typename... Args>
void addConnection(Args... args) {
    auto c = this->connect(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (c) {
        connections.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming it works :) Actually, in my code, I added a clearConnections() that was called somewhere, so obviously the connection was removed haha. I'm just stupid ^^